# JavaScript Classes: storing variables in constructor vs get methods

Tags: javascript, pageobjects

So I am working on a Automation Framework using Page Object Model pattern as well as Cypress (Which is written in JavaScript).

For portions of the page I am making page components (essentially smaller page objects). To reduce maintenance I want to store "locators" for the web elements for easy access (in case they ever change).

I will be referring to these locators further down in the class in larger methods (that combine multiple elements and do things with them). However Im not sure the best way to store them.

Two options come to mind (Im not an expert at JavaScript so there may be a better way. Anyways there is..

**Option 1**: (Store them in simple GET methods like so):

```
saveButton() {
    return cy.contains('Save')
}

nameField() {
    return cy.get('.form-control[name="name"]')
}

descriptionField() {
    return cy.get('.form-control[name="description"]')
}
```

Then when I need to access the locator I just call `nameField().type()` or `saveButton().click()` further down in the class larger methods (Although I guess i'll need to prepend `this` before them.

The other option would be something like this by using the constructor:

**Option 2**: (Use the constructor)

```
class WidgetForm extends PageObject {
    constructor() {
        this.saveButton = 'Save'
        this.nameField = '.form-control[name="name"]'
        this.descriptionField = '.form-control[name="description"]'
    }
//...more code further down that uses these values
```

I can then refer to them in a similar way such as `cy.get(this.nameField).type()` although I suppose I could also store the entire Cypress command function in the constructor value such as:

`this.nameField = cy.get('.form-control[name="name"]')` (At least I assume).

Is there a particular advantage to either? I wish JavaScript allowed constant private values stored in the classes similar to other languages (I know it's coming in ES7 but i'd like to stick with what works now).

Obviously any other suggestions are welcome. For some reason `Option 1` looks better to me. But im not sure if it's slower/uglier defining so many functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1 looks good to me, the organization is more intuitive and the end result looks nicer in my opinion.

```
Class WidgetForm {

    nameField() {
        return cy.get('.form-control[name="name"]')
    }

}
```

then in your tests:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  WidgetForm.nameField().type({"Smith"})
})
```

not sure if you meant this for your second suggestion, but you could use a getter:

```
Class WidgetForm extends PageObject{
    constructor() {
        this.saveButton = 'Save'
        this.nameField = '.form-control[name="name"]'
        this.descriptionField = '.form-control[name="description"]'
    }
    get nameField() {
        return cy.get(this.nameField)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you only define one instance of a getter? (Im not super familiar with them on javascript). For option 2 I mean literally referring to the variable as `this.nameField` in the other functions.

In the end I am just not sure if one is "faster" than the other. etc...

Comment: not sure which is faster, but I don't think there would be a noticeable difference, as the bottleneck would be in the browser.  I would go with whatever one looks nicer and is easier to maintain.